# Arial Unicode MS is not aligning in Jtree

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts, jtree

I am writing a JTree in which I am aligning text which is english and unicode mix.
What I am seeing that after using Arial Unicode MS font, which is unicode and monospaced, text is not aligned as monospaced texts are generally aligned.

The one font I have tested with proper alignment is "Consolas" but since it is not Unicode, it is not showing different language's characters.

A sample code is mentioned for reference:
I have used Korean language :-)

```
package hello;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
public class Jtree_Test extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTree tree;
    public Jtree_Test()
    {
        //create the root node
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        //create the child nodes
        DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vegetables                           test1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode fruitNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test2                                 " + "안녕하세요, 당신은 어떠세요");
        //add the child nodes to the root node
        root.add(vegetableNode);
        root.add(fruitNode);

        //create the tree by passing in the root node
        tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setFont(new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 12));       
        getContentPane().add(tree);

        this.setSize(557, 349);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("JTree Example");       
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Jtree_Test();
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IngAo.png) what you were expecting to see?

Comment: In @AndrewThompson's image this font does not look monospaced at all (`V` is much wider than `t`). May be "MS" in "Arial Unicode MS" means just "Microsoft", but not "Monospaced".

Comment: No Andrew, this should be properly aligned. I have a pic but dont know how to attach here.

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for reply. Yes it is not monospaced like you mentioned. Every character should have same size. I have downloaded and installed Arial Unicode MS font from the official site here (https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081).

Comment: Currently I'm forced to use "Font.MONOSPACED" because "Arial Unicode MS" not working, and this looks ugly. I don't have enough Rep to add bounty on this. : -(

Comment: For the information, I want a monospaced font which contains maximum of language's symbols of around the world. I do not require complex symbols.

Comment: Tip: Add @ThomasFritsch (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. (See also Thomas' comment for an example of notifying me.)

Comment: BTW - @ThomasFritsch makes a good point. Arial is certainly not a monospaced font. The monospaced font seen in Thomas' screenshot seems to be Courier New. Also, space characters are a poor way to achieve alignment in an app with a GUI. Also, does this really call for a tree-table component? Please explain the logic and intended end effect.

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson thanks for handy tip. Thomas has used "Font.Monospaced" font. Also for the space characters they are just added to create a gap between left and right text for clean UI(if the text goes here and there it will not look good) and also right and left texts are dynamic which means left text always english & number of chars vary, right text english or other language & number of chars vary.

Comment: What do you mean by *"and this looks ugly"* ? Of course a monospaced font looks uglier than a variable-spaced font.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I have also used Consolas and Courier and they are looking good in same UI but they do not support many languages though.

Answer (score 1):

Your texts in JTree got mis-aligned because the "Arial Unicode MS" font is not monospaced.

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS):
There is nothing said about "Monospaced". "MS" probably just means "Microsoft".

Just use the "Monospaced" logical font (which is always present in Java),
and it will be fine (at least on my Windows):

```
    //create the root node
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

    //create the child nodes
    DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
            "Vegetables                           test1");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode fruitNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
            "test2                                " + "안녕하세요, 당신은 어떠세요");
    //add the child nodes to the root node
    root.add(vegetableNode);
    root.add(fruitNode);

    //create the tree by passing in the root node
    tree = new JTree(root);
    tree.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));       
    getContentPane().add(tree);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks for answer but check my last comment. :-(